# SAS: How do i split by comma and transpose?

Tags: sas

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide.
I have a new file and i was asked to generate output.
Source:

```
Name    feeder_in    feeder_out   NickName
ABBA    1,2          A,B           ABBA
POLA    1,2          C,D,E         CONS POLA
```

and the desire output:

```
Name             feeder_final    
ABBA              1                
ABBA              2                 
ABBA              A
ABBA              B
POLA              1                 
POLA              2
CONS POLA         C
CONS POLA         D
CONS POLA         E
```

I have been trying myself on handling this but no luck at all.
I tried

```
data test;
catequipment=catx(',',strip(feeder_in),strip(feeder_out));
    do i=1 to countw(catequipment,',');

catequipment=catx(',',strip(feeder_in),strip(feeder_out));
    do i=1 to countw(catequipment,',');
output;
end;

xequipment=newequipment;

run;
```

Does anyone have clue for this?

Comment: This should be simple but you haven't explained the requirements very well. Why does your solution include variables `CATEQUIPMENT` and `XEQUIPMENT`, which aren't mentioned at all in your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding of your requirements, based on the desired output: you want your output to have one observation for each combination of `NAME` and `FEEDER_IN`, plus another observation for each combination of `NICKNAME` and `FEEDER_OUT`.

On that assumption, the code would look something like (not tested):

```
data want;

  set have;
  keep name feeder_final

  * Loop over FEEDER_IN and output one obs for each delimited value;
  do i = 1 to countw(feeder_in, ',');
    feeder_final = scan(feeder_in, i, ',');
    output;
  end;

  * Move the NICKNAME value into NAME;
  name = nickname;

  * Loop over FEEDER_OUT and output one obs for each delimited value;
  do i = 1 to countw(feeder_out, ',');
    feeder_final = scan(feeder_out, i, ',');
    output;
  end;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

When transposing multiple columns you might want to also maintain the source row and column identifiers for further downstream analytics.  The sequence of the values in the **csv** might also be important if you need to do pairwise joining on sequence position of the categorical form -- such as needing to match 1A 2B in row 1 and 1C 2D in row 2.

```
data have;
length name feeder_in feeder_out nickname $20;
input 
Name&   feeder_in&  feeder_out&  NickName&; datalines;
ABBA    1,2          A,B           ABBA
POLA    1,2          C,D,E         CONS POLA
run;

data want;
  _row_ + 1;

  set have;

  feeder = 'in ';
  do seq = 1 to countw(feeder_in,',');
    value = scan(feeder_in,seq,',');
    OUTPUT;
  end;

  feeder = 'out';
  do seq = 1 to countw(feeder_out,',');
    value = scan(feeder_out,seq,',');
    OUTPUT;
  end;

  keep _row_ Name feeder seq value NickName;
run;
```